# Issues with removing attribute from first click(function()) after the second click(function())

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Evening ladies and gents,

I'm in a bit of a pickle trying to figure out how to remove an attribute from a first click function after the second click function has occurred.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.description').hide();

$('.open').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'active');  
    $('.description').hide(); 
    var section = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(section).slideToggle('fast');
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.description').slideUp('fast'); 
    $('.open').removeAttr('id', 'active');   
});
});
</script>
```

What I mean by this is that while I have a close button on my hidden DIV that works properly once it has been clicked (ie. it removes the attribute from the .open class), I can't see to get it to work if the hidden DIV is closed by clicking then next click function.

I'm probably really not explaining myself well, so perhaps an example is easier:

[Click Function Issues Here](http://preview-site-7cc834.ttcportals.com/pages/about-us)

I've only created the DIVs for the first two menu items (Cashier & Deli), so those are the two examples I'm going to use. If you click on the Cashier item, the hidden DIV appears and if you press "CLOSE" on that DIV (aligned right), then the active state disappears on the first menu item. Great. That works.

BUT, if I decide to close the hidden DIV not by the "CLOSE" link, but by clicking the next menu item (Deli), both the Cashier and Deli menu items stay active. So again, my question is whether I can somehow remove it when that second click function on the second menu item occurs.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to remove the attribute in the first place

Comment: Because I don't want the menu item to stay active - ie. stay green as you can see in example on the website.

Comment: It is better to use a class instead .. Just use addClass and removeClass and it should work fine

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't work. Just tried it. It's a matter of adding the class and then removing it when both the .close function occurs as well as the next .open click(fuction()). That's the problem, not whether I added an attribute or a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following a very bad approach by removing the `id` attribute where as you can perform the same task very easily.

Also I see that you are using sprites and you have the associated images in place for it..

So try this approach..

```
$('.description').hide();

$('.open').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.description').hide(); 
    $this.addClass('active');
    // Select all the open tags
    var $tags = $('.open').not($this);
    // Remove the active class for all the items except the clicked open
    $tags.removeClass('active');

    var section = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(section).slideToggle('fast');
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.description').slideUp('fast'); 
    $('.open').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Minus the fact that you forgot to add the active class in after the click(function()), this WORKS!!! Thank you SO MUCH! I'm a total newbie with jQuery, but I'm slowly but surely learning thanks to people like you. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hey hey @Sushanth. There might be one more issue, if you don't mind helping out! So the script works fine, but if you take a look at the site now: [Again with the Issues :(](http://preview-site-7cc834.ttcportals.com/pages/about-us/), once the active class has been activated, it's almost as though the original grey image is showing through - ie. the image looks a bit grainy, unlike when you just hover over the image. Is there any way to combat this? I was thinking through how I might do it in CSS, but I don't think it can be done through CSS...only jQuery?

Comment: Hey @Sushanth - sorry to bug you again, but do you have ANY idea why this script wouldn't be working in IE6/7/8? It works in 9 just fine, but it pretty much hates me in any of others below 9. :(

Comment: I see three errors on the page.. Why is jQuery included multiple times on your page. On page `22 and 43` .. Remove the later or replace the one on line 22 with cdn .. Next is you are checking if `preview_mode == true` on line `54 of default.js` .. Try declaring the variable before you compare it .. Next is it says fancybox not defined.. Check if the script is loading properly and check if something is causing a conflict

Comment: It has to do with the platform I'm building it on. I've actually fixed the script in my case, but the platform I have to build the site on is HORRIBLE for validating code because it adds all these unnecessary scripts. I will take a look at the two instances of jQuery that were included. I included my own link because I didn't even know this platform had that option of including it. /facepalm  Thanks though!